# pod container cannot resolves the host on which it is running

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, dns

I have a unique scenario related to hostname resolution.
I am running a single-node Kubernetes cluster in a server that is in a private network and it doesn't have a DNS server.
So I have configured a host in the `/etc/hosts file` of my laptop.

Now the problem is I can resolve this host from the node(on which the K8s cluster is running) but I cannot resolve it from inside the pod. Following is the `/etc/resolve.conf` of the node:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

I am getting the following error when I do ping to the host from inside the container

ping: bad address 'hostname'

I would appreciate if anyone can help me here.

Comment: Are you as a user trying to connect or as a different pod? If different pod use the service DNS name

Answer (score 0):

Use service DNS (FQDN: **F**ull **Q**ualified **D**omain **N**ame)

If you are exposing your objects (pods, deployments, etc) using a K8S service you can expose them **outside namespaces** with an IP or with FQDN

Here is an example of how to do it:
https://github.com/nirgeier/KubernetesLabs/tree/master/Labs/05-Services#0403-using-the-full-DNS-name

---

[image]

The name (FQDN) will be the same regardless of the IP and cluster in which your code is deployed.

---

#### Official Docs:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname